# Get reference to originating object in event handler in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, backbone.js

How can I get a reference to the ImageListItemView which originated the event in my event handler?

```
addOne: function(image){
    var imageListItemView = new ImageListItemView({model: image});
    imageListItemView.on('imageListItemView:click', this.itemViewClick, this)
    imageListItemView.render();
    this.$el.append(imageListItemView.el); 
},

itemViewClick: function(){
    //Get reference to ImageListItemView that originated event
}
```

Here is the ImageListItemView:

```
// ImageListItemView
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

window.ImageListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy hide', this.remove, this);
        this.model.on('image:selectionChange', this.select, this);
    },

    events : {
        "click" : "onClick"
    },

    className: 'item_view',
    template: _.template($('#image_list_item_view_template').html()),

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

        if(this.model.selected){
            this.$el.addClass('selected');
        }else{
            this.$el.removeClass('selected');
        }
    },

    remove: function(){
        this.$el.remove();
    },

    select: function(){
        this.render();
    },

    onClick: function(e){
        this.trigger('imageListItemView:click');
    }


})
```

And here is the ImageListView:

```
// ImageListView
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

window.ImageListView = Backbone.View.extend({


    className: 'image_list_view',
    tagName: 'nav',

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
    },

    render: function(){
        this.addAll();
        return this;
    },

    addAll: function(){
        this.$el.empty();
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },

    addOne: function(image){
        var imageListItemView = new ImageListItemView({model: image});
        imageListItemView.on('imageListItemView:click', this.itemViewClick, this)
        imageListItemView.render();
        this.$el.append(imageListItemView.el); 
    },

    itemViewClick: function(e){
         //Get reference to ImageListItemView that originated event
         //e is undefined
        //this.collection.setSelectedImage(this.model);
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not an expert with Backbone, but have you tried replacing the event context?

i.e.

```
imageListItemView.on('imageListItemView:click', this.itemViewClick, imageListItemView);
```

If I understand correctly, then `this` inside `itemViewClick` should refer to the `ImageListItemView`.

Worth a try.

Comment: Thanks. Should I be getting an event in my event handler? 'e' is undefined. Do you get an event object with custom events or just DOM events?

Comment: Yes, you should. Sorry for the mess, I'll edit for a complete example.

Comment: No problem. Not getting an event object passed into my handler. Can't work out why.

Comment: I have to ask, is `on` is implemented using jQuery `on` method? Exactly?

Comment: I've added both the relevant classes.

Comment: Should have mentioned you are using Backbone and not jQuery for the events. I'll get back to you in a minute :)

Comment: Apologies. Was in the tags, but I've added 'backbone' to the title.